# Adding equal spaces between a word and a special charecter in VIM

Tags: vim

I have code like:

```
Name,
Age,
Country,
Continent,
```

I want to align it like this using VIM.

```
Name      ,
Age       ,
Country   ,
Continent ,
```

How to do this?

Comment: Do a visual select and shell out to something like `sed -E 's/\<,/ ,/g' | column -t`

Comment: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align can do such stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your buffer only contains those lines…

1. Substitute each trailing comma with some large number of spaces:

   ```
   :%s/,/                           /
   ```

   [image: step 1]
2. Move the cursor where you want your column of commas to be:

   ```
   ell
   ```

   [image: step 2]
3. Enter visual-block mode and extend the selection to the top line:

   ```
   <C-v>gg
   ```

   [image: step 3]
4. Extend the selection to the end of the line:

   ```
   $
   ```

   [image: step 4]
5. Change each line of the block to a comma:

   ```
   c,<Esc>
   ```

   [image: step 5]

Answer (score 0):

Using external command "column":

```
:%! column -t -s, -o, 


-s  .............. separator
-o  .............. output separator
```